# Questions on the use of static classes in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, static, client, server

I am doing a website in Asp MVC 4.

I will like to know if I use static classes to store certain data if the value of these classes are stored on the server or on the client.

Thanks 
Regards

Comment: Please remove asp-classic tag

Comment: Just to note that static classes are evil. You can't unit test them properly, and you may experience many issues with them later on, so you better avoid them altogether. Of course, in some cases you just have no option but to use one or two.

Answer (score 0):

On the server. C# code won't reach the client.

Comment: All right, thank you very much. I will use the cache to strore data in the client. Regards!

Comment: @karlostcp You could my mark my answer as the correct one.